# Spring Boot Maven Plugin - Test fail

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, junit, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I'm having trouble running my application's unit tests. The environment is Spring Boot + JUnit 5 + Maven.

I have a Maven multi-module Spring Boot application.

Tests are in a dedicated module:

```
parent
      - moduleArch
      - moduleApp (SpringBoot)
      - moduleTest
```

When I only use `maven-compiler-plugin` in `moduleApp` everything works fine but when I include the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` (the snippet below) `moduleTest` can't read `moduleApp`.

```
<!-- Build -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please add the concrete error message.

Comment: The message is ```Error:(7,34) java: package com.company.domain.mapper does not exist``` (class not found)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maven integration-test doesn't find my class in same package structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40664101/maven-integration-test-doesnt-find-my-class-in-same-package-structure)